# Mailgun - Unauthenticated email from guest.com

Tags: node.js, mailgun, nodemailer

I have mailgun setup in my node.js using nodemailer and I cannot get it to send emails when I test my route using my REST client. When I directly write the code into the server file, the email sends right away when the server starts.

However, when I write the email api in an app.post and test it with a REST client the email fails on the mailgun side and gets rejected by google??? This is only my assumption because of the error code I am getting.

```
Server response: 550 5.7.1 Unauthenticated email from guest.com is not 
accepted due to domain's 5.7.1 DMARC policy. Please contact the administrator 
of guest.com domain if 5.7.1 this was a legitimate mail. Please visit 5.7.1 
https://support.google.com/mail/answer/2451690 to learn about the 5.7.1 DMARC 
initiative. s12-v6si3013316qtg.362 - gsmtp
```

I've followed the link provided and the documentation says to check with the domain server. I do not understand why I am getting this error because I already authenticated my gmail within mailgun.

I've also tried switching to directly using the mailgun-js middleware. Found three different mailgun-js api from mailgun.com, mailgun-js on github, and mailgun-js on npmjs.com. Got the same error as above.

At a loss. Don't know what to do.

My nodemailer code:

```
const express = require('express');
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
const path = require('path');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');    


const app = express();

const port = 3000;

app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'dist')));       

app.post('/email', (req, res) => {
  let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
          host: 'smtp.mailgun.org',
          port: 587,
          secure: false, // true for 465, false for other ports
          auth: {
              user: 'postmaster@sandboxc8f2ecf64f364ca6ad740e658485c557.mailgun.org',
              pass: 'my API key here'
          },
          tls: {
            rejectUnauthorized: false
          }
      });

      // setup email data with unicode symbols
      let mailOptions = {
          from: req.body.from, // sender address
          to: 'cu0ngpitt@gmail.com', // list of receivers
          subject: 'Someone wrote you from your Online Resume!', // Subject line
          text: req.body.messge, // plain text body
      };

      // send mail with defined transport object
      transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (error, info) => {
          if (error) {
              return console.log(error);
          }
          console.log('Message sent: %s', info.messageId);
          console.log('Preview URL: %s', nodemailer.getTestMessageUrl(info));
      });
});

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Hello world');
});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log('Server running on port ' + port);
})
```

Comment: I don't know what is meant by "I already authenticated my gmail within mailgun". Do you understand DKIM signing and how DMARC works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mailgun responded to my ticket and said due to DMARC security, I am only allowed to send an email with the same domain as my mailgun account.

Since I had a free mailgun account. I had to change my sender address to my free mailgun address, which was postmaster@sandbox"some long string".mailgun.org

If using nodemailer, you can leave off the sender email or hard code it in.

If using mailgun-js, you have to hard code it in.

My old code:

```
// setup email data with unicode symbols
      let mailOptions = {
          from: req.body.from, // sender address
          to: 'cu0ngpitt@gmail.com', // list of receivers
          subject: 'Someone wrote you from your Online Resume!', // Subject line
          text: req.body.messge, // plain text body
      };
```

Corrected code:

```
// setup email data with unicode symbols
      let mailOptions = {
          postmaster@sandbox"some long string".mailgun.org, // sender address
          to: 'cu0ngpitt@gmail.com', // list of receivers
          subject: 'Someone wrote you from your Online Resume!', // Subject line
          text: req.body.messge, // plain text body
      };
```